# Windows 10 IoT enterprise DotNet version

Tags: .net, windows-10-iot-enterprise

I have a very old `.NET 2.0` based application which uses a HID-conform USB device to get data into my application.

The hardware gets upgraded to a **Windows 10 IoT Enterprise** based system.
I did not find which .NET version ships with the operating system.

Is it a good idea to use an older .NET version like `4.5` or should I target a newer version?

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4e4d9320-dccd-4d35-a328-53fe63e90c2f/is-windows-10-iot-core-support-net-framework?forum=WindowsIoT

Comment: This answers the question for Win 10 iot core and not enterprise.